# Configure Security Manager for application that does not allow to set security policy

Tags: java, wildfly, securitymanager, security-policy

I want to deploy a web application ( app.war) on wildfly server.
the web app has its own custom security manager set that does not allow changing java security policy.
I am able to deploy the web app successfully.
But when accessing it, it throws following exception.Is there way to fix the issue without changing the application code

```
at CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:131)
at javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext.setContextID(PolicyContext.java:206)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler$SetContextIDAction.run(JACCContextIdHandler.java:85)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler$SetContextIDAction.run(JACCContextIdHandler.java:74)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doUnchecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:837)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.setContextID(JACCContextIdHandler.java:92)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:65)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The beginning of the exception is missing. Maybe it's not important, but it's hard to tell what's happening with just this stack trace.

Comment: Where is the exception ?

Comment: Question lacks complete stacktrace of exception. And, also let us know api  or framework you are using like Hibernate, Spring, JPA etc.